Prevent Micronaut from converting non-string formats to string from request json body properties
When sending POST requests with a json body to my Micronaut API it is using Jackson's ObjectMapper to deserialize the json to the DTO.
From what I understood, when excepting a String field, it is trying to parse the next token as a String, and if it fails it converts it to a String anyway. This leads to Numbers and Booleans being converted to Strings.
Is there a way to prevent this? I looked at the JacksonConfiguration and didn't find anything that satisfies this requirement.
I looked at custom Serde implementation but couldn't find a way to validate the token as well.
